How to work around MSVC not deducing template template argument
There is a very similar question, but I did not understand how I could apply the workarounds to my code. It was more about achieving generality across different container types: Visual C++ cannot deduce template template parameter
To reiterate: MSVC does not seem to be able to deduce the template template argument to the template function in some cases due to non standard compliant behavior. Clang and GCC compile fine. Is there a way to make the code compile without having to explicitly state the template arguments at every call of the template function?
https://godbolt.org/z/PYe3aoYaM
Side note: I don't think the variadic <class...> should be required, but it solved a reduced problem (also here Clang and GCC accepted it without ...)
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// A generic vector type that should be interchangeable.
template <typename T>
using MyVec = std::vector<T>;  // adding std::allocator<T> does not help

// Type to define a vector of owning references.
template <typename T, template <class...> typename C>
using Group = C<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

// Type to define a vector of non-owning references.
template <typename T, template <class...> typename C>
using GroupRef = C<T*>;

// Convert owning references to non-owning ones.
template <typename T, template <class...> typename C>
GroupRef<T, C> toRef(const Group<T, C>& arg)
{
    GroupRef<T, C> result;
    for (const auto& p : arg) {
        result.push_back(p.get());
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    Group<int, MyVec> g;
    // Error: "no matching overloaded function found"
    auto x = toRef(g);
    // This works:
    //auto x = toRef<int, std::vector>(g);
}



What you try to do is alias template deduction. According to cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction alias template deduction is not supported - see the example at the bottom.

Basically, the current code needs to deduce C, which is MyVec and an alias template. So, it cannot be deduced. If you replace it with std::vector then you can make it work.

@ALX23z Thanks. Well the entire point of that is to hide the vector implementation from the user. I have one more alias: using IntGroup = Group<int, std::vector>; (or add a default to template argument C) where I'd like to replace it for example with boost::container::vector. The MyVec alias then serves the purpose to hide the allocator implementation, which could be e.g. std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator.

Instead of aliases, you could try working with traits - an external template used to redirect to the types/classes/functions you intend to use depending on the class/context you work with.

Not sure if it is acceptable, but adding some Ts... fix compilation with MSVC:
// Type to define a vector of owning references.
template <typename T, template <class...> typename C, typename... Ts>
using Group = C<std::unique_ptr<T>, Ts...>;

// Convert owning references to non-owning ones.
template <typename T, template <class...> typename C, typename...Ts>
GroupRef<T, C> toRef(const Group<T, C, Ts...>& arg)
{
    GroupRef<T, C> result;
    for (const auto& p : arg) {
        result.push_back(p.get());
    }
    return result;
}

Demo
